# Javascript force file caching

Tags: javascript, html, caching

**My website has 200k Active users daily**

I read an article not to long ago about forcing javascript and PHP to cache files. I have never needed to have my files cached before, but now that i am dealing with a massive amount of data being transferred to and from the server i would like to store some of this data locally on the client side.

I don't know if there are any better ways on doing this but essentially, i am considering writing a library using

- HTML5 local storage if its available / [manifest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)
- with a fallback of java if its available
- with a fallback of silverlight if its available.

I am very interested in pursuing this, preferably in JavaScript.

> I would like to know how to cache files using JavaScript

---

**Before anyone thinks i am re-inventing the wheel**

(*example*)
I have several Javascript files which if updated, the browser will not reload the script because it is cached. With version control, i can manage when a user needs to reload cached data.

Comment: The browser caches JavaScript files

Comment: Sometimes. but i would like to cache more than just JavaScript.

Comment: vaguely i am hoping to achieve version control on all data.

Comment: Caching has to be done on the server. You should cache requests from JavaScript not file.

Comment: @wrangler caching is done on the client side.

Comment: It can be both actually. The client can cache files, the server can cache responses to requests

Comment: @l19 true, but i am only looking to cache files, i havent considered caching responses which i might look into that later now that you have enlightened me

Comment: Have a look at the AppCache API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: woah, its that easy.. Thanks!!

Comment: Another thing to consider if your site is getting heavy traffic and serving a lot of the same resources multiple times is using a CDN. I am familiar with AWS Cloudfront but there are a lot of options out there. A CDN is really helpful for taking load off of your servers while improving user load times at the same time.

Comment: @jaredkwright my content data network is powered by AWS. The issue here is not about content routing; more or less, its about preventing repetitive & sometimes consecutive request for data to the server(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). Basically, for every request you should specify the `cache-control` header field in the response, indicating when a fresh content will be available. The formal definition of the [cache-control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header field is as follows:

> The Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives
>   that MUST be obeyed by all caching mechanisms along the
>   request/response chain. The directives specify behavior intended to
>   prevent caches from adversely interfering with the request or
>   response. These directives typically override the default caching
>   algorithms. Cache directives are unidirectional in that the presence
>   of a directive in a request does not imply that the same directive is
>   to be given in the response.

The field is usually specified along the lines of

`cache-control: private|public, max-age=[, no-cache]`.

> **public**
>
> Indicates that the response MAY be cached by any cache, even if
>   it would normally be non-cacheable or cacheable only within a non-
>   shared cache. (See also Authorization, section 14.8, for additional
>   details.)
>
> **private**
>
> Indicates that all or part of the response message
>   is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared
>   cache. This allows an origin server to state that the specified parts
>   of the response are intended for only one user and are not a valid
>   response for requests by other users. A private (non-shared) cache MAY
>   cache the response. Note: This usage of the word private only controls
>   where the response may be cached, and cannot ensure the privacy of the
>   message content.
>
> **no-cache**
>
> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then
>   a cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request
>   without successful revalidation with the origin server. This allows an
>   origin server to prevent caching even by caches that have been
>   configured to return stale responses to client requests. If the
>   no-cache directive does specify one or more field-names, then a cache
>   MAY use the response to satisfy a subsequent request, subject to any
>   other restrictions on caching. However, the specified field-name(s)
>   MUST NOT be sent in the response to a subsequent request without
>   successful revalidation with the origin server. This allows an origin
>   server to prevent the re-use of certain header fields in a response,
>   while still allowing caching of the rest of the response.

For example, `cache-control: private, max-age=86400, no-cache` directs the client to cache a response and reuse it until **86400** ***seconds*** (24 hours) have elapsed. However, things may change before that time elapses. `no-cache` directive causes a revalidation each time. It is like the browser asking each time ***may I really present your user with the cached content?*** Together with the ***[ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19)*** header, you will be able to push important changes to your user before previously cached content expires.

During revalidation, an Etag present in a response is compared with the one provided previously in a request for same resource. If they are same, it reassures that the resource has not changed, thus, cache is really valid. Else if they differ, then the resource content has changed, and the new content will be given as response to the user.

Read more about HTTP caching:

1. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#validating-cached-responses-with-etags
2. http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Meanwhile, note that the use of the [Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is mainly applicable if you wish to provide your users with offline content.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you *would* reinvent the wheel. Instead of trying to create a second cache on top of a browser's built-in cache, you should take advantage of a proxy like CloudFlare to handle caching of static assets for you.

As for the issue of cached files not updating, a common technique to force resources to be re-requested is to add a query string parameter containing the file's last modification time (e.g. `/js/script.js?1441538979`), which normally forces the browser to re-download the file.